# UK visitor visa validity

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, visa-expiration

Good day. I have a question regarding the validity of a visitor visa please: for instance, your visa expires on November 20, 2019 and you plan to visit on November 8 to 15, will you be allowed entry to the UK? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Your visit dates are in the validity period of your visa. I can’t guarantee you won’t be refused entry at all, as you could be refused for other reasons but you won’t be refused based on the validity of your visa.